# Can't install docker, ca problems with curl

Tags: 18.04, docker, curl, certificates

I am trying install docker from there instructions:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver

I am running the command:

`$ sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

And get:

```
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran this program and it fixed my certificate store:

`$ sudo update-ca-certificates`

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to run below command first to install the certificates first before -

```
$ sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
```

I have documented the steps to installdocker-ce in below tutorial. Hope this will help -

https://crunchytechbytz.wordpress.com/2018/06/25/how-to-install-docker-in-ubuntu-18-04/